# Deserialize scientific notation to long with System.Text.Json

Tags: json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have JSON with a number in scientific notation, e.g. `1.83E+2`. Deserializing it with Json.NET to a `long` has worked well for me, but when I replace the deserializer with the new one in System.Text.Json it throws an `JsonException`:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int64. ...'

Here is a reproducible example:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    // test1 is 183
    var test1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(@"{""Bar"": 1.83E+2}"); 

    // throws JsonException
    var test2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(@"{""Bar"": 1.83E+2}");
}

public class Foo
{
    public long Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After asking the .NET Core team they provided [this solution](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42556#issuecomment-552919838) to the problem:

```
static void Main()
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new CustomInt64Converter() }
    };

    // test1 is 183
    var test1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(@"{""Bar"": 1.83E+2}");

    // test2 is 183
    var test2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(@"{""Bar"": 1.83E+2}", options);
}

public class Foo
{
    public long Bar { get; set; }
}

public class CustomInt64Converter : JsonConverter<long>
{
    public override long Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.TryGetInt64(out var result) ? result : Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetDecimal());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, long value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` doesn't support converting scientific notation into a `long`. Instead. you need to serialise to `double` or `decimal` and process that number instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    public double Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a reason for that? Has that been discussed by the devs?

Comment: I have no idea, you better ask the devs!